# When does $\mathcal{O}_Y = f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ hold?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, pushforward

In a comment to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635501/geometric-intuition-for-the-stein-factorization-theorem) about Stein factorization, [Tabes Bridges](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/36394/tabes-bridges) writes

> Moduli technicalities (particularly in positive characteristic), the condition $f_∗\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y$ basically means that the fibers of $f$ are connected.

I wonder what those technicalities actually are, especially in characteristic zero.

In the proof of **Corollary III 11.4**, Hartshorne actually proves the statement

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a birational projective morphism of noetherian integral schemes, and assume that $Y$ is normal. Then $f_* \mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_Y$.

Are there other criterions, where I don't need normality?

*Context* I have a rather concrete morphism $X \to \mathbb{P}^n$ and I want to show that its image is a smooth projective variety. So my advisor suggested to look at the theorem of formal functions, and calculate $\lim H^i(X_n, \mathcal{O}_n)$ to show that $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ (resp. its completion) is regular. But the theorem on formal functions only deals with the completion of $(f_* \mathcal{O}_X)_y$, so I think that I need $\mathcal{O}_Y = f_* \mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: Take a look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63301/when-will-the-pushforward-of-a-structure-sheaf-still-be-a-structure-sheaf